# Writing newlines to files

Tags: haskell, io

How can I write a string that contains newlines ("\n") to a file so that each string is on a new line in the file?

I have an accumulator function that iterates over some data and incrementally constructs a string (that contains information) for each element of the data. I don't want to write to the file every step so I'm appending the strings in each step. I do this so I can write the string in one time and limit the amount of IO.

Adding a newline to the string via `str ++ "\n"` doesn't work, `hPrint h str` will just print `"\n"` instead of starting on a new line.

I've tried accumulating a list of strings, instead of one big string, and iterating over the list and printing each string via `hPrint`. This works for the newlines but it also prints the quotation marks around each string on every line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `hPrint` to write the strings to the file. Just like regular `print` it outputs the result of `show`, which produces a debugging-friendly version of the string with control characters and line endings escaped (and the surrounding quotes).

Use `hPutStr` or `hPutStrLn` instead. They will write the string to the file as-is (well, the latter adds a newline at the end).

Comment: I'm now iterating over my list of strings and writing each one to the file using `hPutStrLn`. I think that's what you had in mind. Either way, it's working.

Answer (score 1):

The probably idiomatic solution to what you try to do is to simply aggregate the resulting strings in a list. Then, use the `unlines` prelude function which has the signature `unlines :: [String] -> String` and does your `\n` business for you.

Then, writing the string to disk can be done with help of `writeFile` which has the signature: `writeFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()`.

Haskell is lazy. As such, it sometimes helps to think of Haskell lists as enumerators (C# like IEnumerable). This means here, that trying to compute line wise, then build the string manually and write it line by line is not really necessary. Just as `readFile` works lazily, so then does e.g. `lines`. In other words, you gain nothing if you try to "optimize" code which looks in its genuine form similar to this:

```
main = do
    input <- readFile "infile"
    writeFile "outfile" ((unlines . process) (lines input))
    where 
        process inputLines = -- whatever you do
```

Comment: The problem isn't the strings, it's how they're written to the file. Using `hPrint` on `unlines ["foo", "bar"]` won't yield any better results than `hPrint "foo\nbar"`.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. This is still writing the quotation marks to the file.